# Is an end-2-end javascript stack secure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, couchdb

I want to build a multi tenent cloud app. My stack is javascript / json end-2-end: The user inputs data in the browser which jquery turns to json, sends to my node.js server, which in turn stores it as json in couchdb. When fetching data json goes the other way around. If the user injects something to this json is there anywhere in the above stack this json is actually evaludated? If yes I need to sanitize it. How robust is json sanitization? Or will a sandbox help? how robust is it?

This is a multi tenent environment and a lot of secret data of users and companies will be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look on [Caja](https://github.com/theSmaw/Caja-HTML-Sanitizer) or [Node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator)

- Caja is implementation of Google Caja sanitizer
- Node-validator is a node validator/sanitizer, here [express node-validator wrapper](https://github.com/Dream-Web/express-validate)

Good luck

Comment: thanks. do you think it is secure enough to protect corporate data or is the world of json sanitizers more of a collection of heuristics and best practices which are not always hacker proof?

Comment: I think nodejs is too young to become a corporate standart. But JSON isn't it's weak point because JSON is too simple and very secure standart. Only html and javascript passed in JSON could be dangerous and you should to think about this related to every data-type you have used. If you want to create really secure site you should to think about positive validation (not negative). I mean that you should make a decision what to apply neither what to deny.

Comment: Is nodejs still too risky even if I use reverse proxy? Also, by "js inside json" you mean only if I explicitly expect to get it and run it right? Otherwise it is just a string which I never execute.

Comment: Reverse proxy is good idea, but it will slow up your application. Is it critical for you? And yes if you want eval data or put it's result on the page with html-enabled in the value.

Comment: Article about [gmail hacking](http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com/2006/01/advanced-web-attack-techniques-using.html) will be also helpful to understand risks and weak points.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest defense-in-depth (i.e. multiple overlapping security mechanisms. Richard and Pasha both make excellent suggestions.

Something else to do is use [CouchDB data validation](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/validation.html) features. You write a `validate_doc_update` function in Javascript. This function will run for *every* change to the database. The function can decide whether the data is acceptable or not.

Validation runs deep, in the CouchDB server itself. Therefore, if you have a good validation function, it is impossible for bad data to be stored at all.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js uses JSON.parse to evaluate JSON data. JSON.parse uses the strict JSON syntax which does not allow for functions to be declared within the data string. It also means that data keys must be double-quoted strings, and values can only be Boolean, Number, String, Array, or Object.

Comment: thanks. I assume this is wrt the nodejs framework. what about libraries? is there any compelling reason for them to do quick eval() shortcuts or does the nodejs platform does the parsing for them? also what about couchdb?

Comment: My understanding is that `JSON.parse` is (1) safer but also (2) faster than `eval()`. If you are concerned about security, I suggest you never use eval.

Comment: Each library is executed in its own sandbox using the vm module:

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/vm.html

The require() function uses the vm module. This prevents modules from interfering with eachother. There is no need to eval anything from the server.